# Highlighting buttons in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I created a button in my game with a rectangle of width 50 and height 30 at position (150,50) and orange color and i wanted to change its color into a lighter orange when the user hovers the cursor over it to show that it is clickable. I just found a way to detect the position of the cursor using the collidepoint method on the rectangle's variable, but i still couldn't figure out how to change the color. Can anyone tip me a piece of code to do this?

Comment: I just found a way to detect the position of the cursor using the collidepoint method on the rectangle's variable, but i still couldn't figure out how to change the color.

Comment: got to show us the code you're having a challenge with so we correct it for you.

Comment: Ok. Wait a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the location of your pointer and check if it's colliding with your button's rectangle:

```
lighter_orange = (255, 165, 0) #RGB orange
while True:
    btn_rect = button.image.get_rect() # rect of button's image (a pygame.Surface)
    pointer = pygame.mouse.get_pos() # (x, y) location of pointer in every frame
    if btn_rect.collidepoint(pointer): # if pointer is inside btn_rect
        button.fill(lighter_orange)
```

As you can see, Pygame's Surface class has a fill() method that covers the surface with the colour you pass it.